# How to create global preloader to all components. Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, preloader

I need to create a component which will add preloader (image with semi-transparent background) to all components, which loading or fetching data from service. I have some routable blocks on page. And I need to show preloader over the block, which working in the moment. Which of events should I handle? And how to make it globaly? Thank you.

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you actually try to accomplish. Check the help topics about how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could start by creating a custom directive for e.g `<my-loader></my-loader>` and in that component you could add your Preloader, images etc then by simply adding it to any of your component view by including it in `directive[]`. Hope this answers as the question itself is quite abstract , some snippet would definitely help.

Comment: I have made more generic solution to this problem. but would like to know if OP is talking about `loader/spinner` or not.